# Motorola G4 refuses to connect to iPhone's Hotspot

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, ios, motorola-moto-g-4g

I have an odd situation, I recently purchased an iPhone XS and for some reason, my older Moto G4 cannot connect to the hotspot provided by the new phone.

The situation is odd because other phones, both Android and iOS,  can connect and use the internet from the iPhone XS without any issues. yes I do have a sharing data plan.

The Motorola G4 seems to be working fine as it can connect to other hotspots,  iOS devices, Android devices, and routers from my home and coffee shops, and use their internet without problems.

The Moto G4 can connect to the 2Ghz and 5Ghz networks in my house correctly.

I've hard reset both the Moto G4 and the iPhone phones.

I changed several times the password on the iPhone XS hotspot as well as the phone name. I tried setting passwords with all caps letters, all numbers, all lowercase, 123456789, a mix of both, but it just refuses to connect.

The Moto G4 always says authentication failed, but I am 100% confident that the password is correct.

If I swap the sim cards to use the Moto G4 as a hotspot then, the iPhone XS can connect to the G4 without problems.

My mobile provider is T-Mobile.

The MotoG4 can also get internet from the iPhone using Bluetooth connection but this is a less than an ideal scenario.

I'll appreciate any clues to solve this mystery.

Edit: Additional information from someone with the same problem:

Getting the same problem with iPhone Xs and iPhone 11 as hotspots

Moto E4 getting Authentication Failed, if verbose is enabled in developer mode it goes authentication failure 1-5 before quitting

I have done a Direct Firmware Update on the iPhone Xs with no change. I have factory reset 2 of the Motos and no change.

All devices running the latest OS that auto-update allows.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Moto G4 and iPhone 11

Answer (score 0):

The older devices sometimes just do not connect to networks with new Wi-Fi encryption modes. It can be an reason because as you said your Moto G4 connects to other wifi spots.
You can try to change region on your G4.
Or change your encryption method on your iphone.